Pine Script: draw horizontal line from inputs and change line from chart by dragging from single drag point
In a Pine Script indicator I want to use a horizontal line in calculating a setup. This horizontal line changes from time to time and needs to be placed and then repositioned after every setup by the user. But, in Pine Script it's not possible to access user drawings.
The solution I came up with is to draw the horizontal line from two user inputs: a price input and a time input.
Once the horizontal line is configured the first time, I want to repositioned it from the chart by clicking and dragging from the indicator 'drag point(s)'. The draggable points appear when the user hovers elements from the indicator, in this case the horizontal line, on the chart.
This works but there's one problem:
When I hover over the indicator in the chart, I do get drag point options to reposition the horizontal line. But I have to do it in two steps. The price (y axis) and the time (x axis) point have separate drag points.
My question is: can this be changed so I have one drag point for both, so the line can be repositioned from just one drag point?
The current code I use for the horizontal line is as follows:
//@version=5
indicator(title="Horizontal line", overlay=true)

// HORIZONTAL LINE
hLinePrice                  = input.price( 0, title="Horizontal line price" )
hLineTimeStart              = input.time( timestamp("26 July 2024 15:00 -0500"), title="Horizontal line time")
hLineBarsBack               = (time - hLineTimeStart) / (1000 * timeframe.in_seconds(timeframe.period))

var line horizontalLine     = na

if not barstate.isconfirmed or (barstate.isrealtime and barstate.islast and not barstate.isconfirmed)
    horizontalLine := line.new(x1=bar_index[hLineBarsBack], y1=hLinePrice, x2=bar_index, y2=hLinePrice, width=1, extend=extend.right)
    
    line.set_color(id=horizontalLine, color=color.black)
    line.set_style(id=horizontalLine, style=line.style_solid)

if barstate.isconfirmed
    line.delete(id=horizontalLine)


at first instead of line use hline.
next horizon line start from infinity candle ago and continue to infinity candle.
so, you should use hline and give it (y_axis)means price.so delete all and use this function.
hline(price, title, color, linestyle, linewidth, editable, display)


I tried this and I'll share my code below.
However, it's not working very smoothly. Too many times when I drag the line to reposition it in de chart, TradingView places the line on a different location than dragged/indicated. Which is annoying.
// HORIZONTAL LINE hLinePrice                  = input.price( defval=0, title="Horizontal line price") hline(price=hLinePrice, title="Horizontal line", color=color.black, linestyle=hline.style_solid)
So other solutions are welcome.

i got What's the problem
you should write 0.0 instead 0 for hlineprice because you write hlineprice is a input and give price.
price is a float number but you give 0 to defval of input so it will return exception and you should just write this
hlineprice = input.price(defval = 0.0,title="Horizontal line price")

